# javascript login popup in opencart

Tags: javascript, php, opencart

Friends I am having a strange issue with no idea what went wrong.

my company asked me to show a opopup with login options in opencart i.e. user cant browse products unless he/she register or login.

i used the following script to do that

**ISSUE**
it works fine once or twice after that the popup shows blank.

**Codes**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
$("#logpop").append('<div id="loginbox" class="loginbox"></div>');var a=$("#welcome a").first().html();
$("#welcome a").first().html('<span class="login"></span>');$("#welcome a .login").html(a);-1!=$("#welcome a[href]").first().attr("href").indexOf("register")?($("#loginbox").load("index.php?route=account/login .right form"), $("#loginbox").css("right","50px")):
($("#loginbox").load("index.php?route=account/account #content"),$("#loginbox").css("right","40px"));
$("#welcome > a .login").live("hover",function(){$("#welcome").addClass("active");$("#loginbox .breadcrumb").remove();$("#loginbox h1").remove();});
});

$(document).ready(function(){
-1==$(location).attr("href").indexOf("account/logout")&&$.cookie("url",$(location).attr("href"));$("#welcome a").first().removeAttr("href");$("#logpop").first().css("display","none");$("#login_dimming").first().css("display","none");   
});
</script>
```

friends can you please help me fix this problem

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing this via JS I'd suggest implementing a *preAction* that will check whether the user is logged-in and if not, it will redirect to the login/register screen.

How to implement a *preAction*: look into `index.php` where a preAction for maintenance mode is registered:

```
// Maintenance Mode
$controller->addPreAction(new Action('common/maintenance'));
```

You can add a new one:

```
// Logged-in user required
$controller->addPreAction(new Action('common/login'));
```

and then of course look into the `catalog/controller/common/maintenance.php` to see how it is done. You can implement something similar in Your new `catalog/controller/common/login.php`:

```
<?php
class ControllerCommonLogin extends Controller {
    public function index() {
        if (!$this->customer->isLogged()) {
            return $this->forward('account/login');
        }
    }
}
```

This is much easier, more MVC and better way of checking whether user is logged-in before he can start shopping.

Comment: i think the problem is that content from login page do not load if the url is sitename.com.
but it loads and works properly if the URL is www.sitename.com

Comment: And yet I suggest doing this using the MVC approach shown above. If I turn off the JS I'd be able to overcome Your popup and to see the products even if not logged in. Think about it.

Comment: It's upon You to explain why the popup is a *no-go* and to convince them to want it the correct and clean way.